# Getting error in Click method of Selenium in python, when i find the element from div id

Tags: python, testing, selenium, xpath, phantomjs

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Testone(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.cookiesEnabled = 'True'
        self.driver.set_window_size(1366,768)

    def test_url(self):
        max_wait = 10
        self.driver.get("http://ads.ibibo.com/afr.php?z=50005")
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(max_wait)
        self.assertIn("Advertisement", self.driver.title)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img").click()
        #self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img").click()


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am getting this screen

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 76
    while not utils.is_connectable(self.port):
ResourceWarning: unclosed 
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_url (__main__.Testone)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\siddharth.jain\Documents\Automation\test.py", line 28, in test_url
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='']/a/img").click()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 230, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//div[@id='']/a/img'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"103","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:57252","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.4"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"value\": \"//div[@id='']/a/img\", \"using\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"da0e56b0-8996-11e4-96ef-e721b9f30c36\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/da0e56b0-8996-11e4-96ef-e721b9f30c36/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 3.075s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: please provide the XML input as well

Answer (score 0):

[Waiting for an element explicitly](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) made it work for me:

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class Testone(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.cookiesEnabled = 'True'
        self.driver.set_window_size(1366,768)

    def test_url(self):
        max_wait = 10
        self.driver.get("http://ads.ibibo.com/afr.php?z=50005")
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(max_wait)
        self.assertIn("Advertisement", self.driver.title)

        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img"))
        )
        element.click()


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```